# Functional test with services API layer and CRM

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

Here is my project architecture components:

- Front-end (Drupal crm)
- Symfony 2 services (API layer)
- CRM (external service to store users)

I would like to setup functional testing with [codeception](http://codeception.com/) to test subscription part of my application. 
Now, here is the process for subscription:

1/ Display form in front-end

2/ When form is submitted data is post to Services

3/ Services establish a connexion with the CRM and return a Json response to front-end.

4/ Front-end redirect and display a success message (or errors).

I need to clean up my data before run my test (test is get on /subscription, fill form, submit and test response). In fact, if a user exist in CRM, I need to delete it if I want test a success case.
In my case, I don't have a way to delete a specific user before running my test (no route in API to delete a user).

How can I achieve this? I'm not supposed to have a detached database to test this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write background in feature file to delete data for each scenario. I quickly visited codeception and it is BDD testing framework.

```
Feature: Test Subscription 
  As a system admin 
  I want to test subscription system of "APPLICATION NAME"


  Background:
    Given delete all test data from system
    And test data is delete successfully

Scenario: Create User in CRM
    Given I am logged in as system admin
    When I try to click to new customer
    And Enter ...
    And Enter......
    When I click on customer list
    Then I should see created customer in list
```

Background will run after each scenario and do job for you.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not really about implementation in the framework. It's more an architectural question with my environment. I'll edit my question.

Comment: if you are trying to do in backend some where and using BDD it will confuse team member about deleting data. using background everyone know that you are deleting.